# django deployment using ubuntu ec2 (bitnami)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm trying to deploy my django app. I have it hooked up to an Ubuntu ec2 with bitnami on a amazon EC2 server.

**1. How do I access my local deployment of the app inside my ec2?**: I connect to my ec2 via my macbook terminal. I run python manage.py runserver inside the terminal and it says it's connected to the localhost of the ec2. Great. But how do I access the localhost of the ec2 at the 127.0.0.1:8000 website when I only can talk to it through terminal?

**2. I'm having trouble setting up my templates**: I keep getting the error *Template does not exist*

The template-loader postmortem showed:

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>
> Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>
> /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.9-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
>
> /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.9-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/dashboard.html (File does not exist)

Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't use runserver there at all. There is a whole section of the Django docs about how to deploy to production.

Answer (score 0):

1. you want run your django web by python manage.py runserver.
   then you should set your ec2 server ip for to make other computer access your django.

   `python manage.py runserver ***.***.***.***:80`

then you can access

```
'***.***.***.***:80'
```

in your safari or chrome.

2. to answer your question, i need more detail.. like settings.py's template_dir or etc. template_loader check your settings.py;s template directory.